# Cannot override "Connection" header in XPages' HttpServletResponse

Tags: jsf, servlets, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, xpages

In my XPages application I want to keep the connection alive when sending a XMLHttpRequest from one XPage to another. Therefore, I set the "Connection" header to "**keep-alive**".

On the client-side I have:

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection","keep-alive");
```

and on the server-side (in the afterRenderResponse event of the responding XPage) I use:

```
response=facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.setHeader("Connection","keep-alive");
```

When inspecting the request and the response (with FireBug), it turns out that the request headers contain "**Connection = keep-alive**" (as expected), but the response headers contain "**Connection = close**".

Does anybody know how to override this header?

Comment: Never done that specifically, but it might very well be that the XPages engine simple overrides the header. If you want more control over the in- and output of the request (and headers), consider using servlets in the NSF as Eric McCormick described here: http://edm00se.io/servlet-series/.

Comment: @MarkLeusink: Thanks for the tip, but the advantage of using a XPage for the response is that I can directly use all my SSJS code in the afterRenderResponse event. I guess if I'd create a Java servlet I'd have to put a lot of effort into running the SSJS from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: In the **xsp.properties** file set `xsp.compress.mode=gzip`. This is equal to setting `Compression = "GZip, set content length"` under Xsp Properties / Page Generation.

---

**EXPLANATION**: My application used the server default for compression, which is `gzip-nolength`. When the content length is not set, the XPages' response (XspHttpServletResponse) seems to always set the "Connection" header to "close". After setting the content length the "Connection" header is no longer present and the connection is kept alive by default.